# Autorun a module

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have this module running in one of my files. It works well and it does what it needs to. However, It's a pain to run it mannually every time that I need it to happen. Is there any way to have it run automatically every time a pivot table is refreshed or everytime the sheet changes?

```
Sub CopyValuesAndNumberFormats()
'Update 20130815
Dim CopyRng As Range, PasteRng As Range
xTitleId = "HeatMapUpdateSP"
Set CopyRng = Application.Selection
Set CopyRng = Range("D2:G4")
Set PasteRng = Range("D11:G13")
CopyRng.Copy
PasteRng.Parent.Activate
PasteRng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
PasteRng.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

"Every time the sheet changes"...

From your VBE, click on "YourSheet" and add the code to the event `Worksheet_Change`. It will look something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    YourModule.CopyValuesAndNumberFormats
End Sub
```

"Every time the pivot table is updated"...

Same logic, but with a different event of the worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    YourModule.CopyValuesAndNumberFormats
End Sub
```

**NOTE:** You might want to add these two private macros to each of your sheet where you want the code to be executed.